# Task :@react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED React Native 0.59.9 React Viro

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on my final project and the code always had been worked fine. HOwever, now when I run react-native run-android --variant=gvrDebug,its showing an error with Masked View

[image]

[image]

I really need help

[image]

I need to solve this bug